# Is there an standard algorithm for finding the union of list items

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm not sure what to call this algorithm so that's part of the reason I'm not not sure it if exists already.

(note: I'm using some macro's to simplify the input for illustration purposes)

```
std::vector<BYTE> itemlist;

itemlist.push_back( 1000 );
itemlist.push_back( 0001 );
itemlist.push_back( 0001 );
itemlist.push_back( 0010 );
itemlist.push_back( 0100 );
itemlist.push_back( 0011 );
itemlist.push_back( 0001 );
itemlist.push_back( 1000 );

std::list<std::vector<int>> results = Confab(itemlist);
```

expected results:

```
{ [ 1,2,3,5,6], [4], [0,7] }
```

So I'm using the BYTE as a bit mask to find the union of the members. The key is I'm also updating the mask as well. So items 1 and 2 have nothing in common, but item 5 merges with either.

I'm looking for any insights about how to do this in the least number of passes. In the real world I'm using DWORDs.

*edit* I forgot to mention that any item with 0000 means the item gets its own entry.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to split a set into multiple sets where the members of each result set fits the criteria of `(a ^ b) & a == a`.  Is that correct?

Comment: Your Rep number is so *round*... I'm finding it difficult to up vote this...

Comment: I now needed some moment to figure out what you mean with those bits. Now I got it: What you're looking for is called "union-find", or "disjoint-set". It can be implemented using a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off with an array of list pointers equal to the number of bits you have, consisting of null pointers to start off with.

For each element:

- If none of the array elements corresponding to the bits are set, create a new list and set all the array elements to point to the list.
- Otherwise, for each initialized array element, merge the lists, making the pointers point to the new list. Also set all uninitialized array elements to the new list.
- Add an auto-incremented value to the new list.

Go through the array, outputting all unique lists (to only process unique lists, you can set some indicator once you've processed the list, so you don't process it twice).

Oh right, we also need [union-find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) here - otherwise merging the lists may leave some other elements pointing to the old list.

**A bit more on the union-find algorithm:**

This algorithm uses a forest (a bunch of tree data structures), but instead of the standard tree format where parents point to children, the children instead point to their parent, and a parent can have any number of children. We start off with a tree containing just a single element for each set (so, in our case, whenever we create a new list, we'd create a new set). The root can be thought of an indicator of the set which this entire tree belongs to. To merge two sets, we make one of the roots point to the other root, so the trees would be combined under the other root.

In our case, we'd have each root also store a list of elements. Whenever we want to merge lists as specified above, we'd first iterate up each tree to see which set it belongs to, and merge the sets (and their lists) if they belong to different sets, or do nothing otherwise.

This is just a basic description union-find, you may need to read up on it some more if you're struggling to understand some of the complexities here.

**Running time analysis:**

You can merge lists in constant time (see [`list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)). For 32 bits, there can never be more than 31 merges in total, as there can never be more sets, thus lists, than the number of bits, so you'd just mostly be doing checking.

The added complexity of the union-find algorithm should be negligible here, especially if you use some well-known optimizations.

This (if implemented correctly) is linear in the number of bits times the number of input elements, which you can't do better than ([asymptotically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) speaking), as you at least need to look at every bit of every element in the input.

**Example:** (not showing union-find, for simplicity)

4 bits, so an array of 4 lists.

```
[NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL]
```

Process `1000`. The first bit isn't set, so create a new list containing `0` and make that element point to it.

```
 [0]
  ^
  |
[   ,NULL,NULL,NULL]
```

Process `0001`. The last bit isn't set, so create a new list containing `1` and make that element point to it.

```
 [0]           [1]
  ^             ^
  |             |
[   ,NULL,NULL,   ]
```

Process `0001`. The last bit is set, so just add `2`.

```
 [0]           [1,2]
  ^             ^
  |             |
[   ,NULL,NULL,   ]
```

Process `0010`. The second-last bit isn't set, so create a new list containing `3` and make that element point to it.

```
 [0]      [3] [1,2]
  ^        ^   ^
  |        |   |
[   ,NULL,   ,   ]
```

Process `0100`. The second bit isn't set, so create a new list containing `4` and make that element point to it.

```
 [0] [4] [3] [1,2]
  ^   ^   ^   ^
  |   |   |   |
[   ,   ,   ,   ]
```

Process `0011`. The second-last and last bits are set, so merge them and add `5`.

```
 [0] [4] [1,2,3,5]
  ^   ^   ^   ^
  |   |   |   |
[   ,   ,   ,   ]
```

Process `0001`. The last bit is set, so just add `6`.

```
 [0] [4] [1,2,3,5,6]
  ^   ^   ^   ^
  |   |   |   |
[   ,   ,   ,   ]
```

Process `1000`. The first bit is set, so just add `7`.

```
 [0,7] [4] [1,2,3,5,6]
  ^     ^   ^   ^
  |     |   |   |
[   ,     ,   ,   ]
```

Now we have our 3 lists, as required.

Comment: The real data is using 32bits. I'd like some info that this approach doesn't use excessive merges when the itemlist is smaller than 32.

Comment: I can imagine if the data is 11101101110111110000000000001001, there would be plenty of excessive merges due to all the extra 1's on each item.

Comment: You can merge in constant time (see [list::splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)), but yes, there may be a merge for each bit (-1), but there can never be more than 31 merges *in total*, as there can never be more lists than the number of bits, so you'd just mostly be doing checking. Note that this (if implemented correctly) is linear in the number of bits times the number of input elements, which you can't do better than ([asymptotically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) speaking), as you at least need to look at every bit of every element in the input.

Comment: I guess I'm missing the part where you limit to (bits -1) merges. What if the next two items are 0011 and 0011. How are you detecting that these do not need additional merges?

Comment: @BenL If you get 0011, you'd merge the last two lists. Then if you get 0011 again, you'd see that they both point to the same list, and do nothing - this is done with the union-find algorithm, which I added a bit on to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A 'disjoint-set' is quite a general approach (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Some adaptation can be used here as well.

One possible approach:

- Consider a list `A = {1000, 0100, 0010, 0001}` - each element represents a set and at the beginning all sets are disjoint.
- For each element `v` in your list (like `1010`) find corresponding sets in `A` (all `e` in `A` s.t. `e & v != 0`).
- Join those elements `e1,e2,...`: Remove them from `A` and add `e1|e2|...` to `A`.

Finally, `A` represents all sets. You can classify each item `e` by finding an `a` in `A` s.t. `a & e == e`.